# FBX - In a FBX file, which data should I use to build the skeleton of a model and animate it?

Tags: file, animation, data-structures, fbx, 3d-model

For learning purposes, I'm writing a FBX file reader in c++, in order to understand how this kind of 3D models are working. I must specify that I already successfully wrote a .x file reader in the past, so I'm comfortable with concepts like skeleton, bones and skin weights.

At this point I wrote a code able to read and parse the FBX file content, and extract and show the basic model in its T pose. I also assume that I correctly understood the way the FBX data are structured, and how to link the elements together and rebuild the important hierarchies like the skeleton.

However I'm a little puzzled about which data I need to use for the bones and animations. About the first ones I have a hierarchy of deformers, which each contains more or less data like that:

```
Deformer: 46748048, "SubDeformer::clavicle_r_adult_female", "Cluster" {
    Version: 100
    UserData: "", ""
    Indexes: *519 {
        a: 1988,2000,2001,2002,2003,7898,7899,7900,7901,7902,7903,7904,7905,7906,7907,7908,7909,7910,7911,7912,7913,7914,7915,7916,7917,7918,7919,7920,7921,7922,7923,7924,7925,7926,7927,7928,7929,7930,7931,7932,7933,7934,7935,7936,7937,7938,7939,7940,7941,7942,7943,7944,7945,7946,7947,7948,7949,7950,7951,7952,7953,7954,7955,7956,7957,7958,7959,7960,7961,7962,7963,7964,7965,7966,7967,7968,7969,7970,7971,7972,7973,7974,7975,7976,7977,7978,7979,7980,7981,7982,7983,7984,7985,7986,7987,7988,7989,7990,7991,7992,7993,8000,8001,8002,8003,8004,8005,8012,8013,8014,8015,8016,8017,8024,8025,8026,8027,8028,8029,8030,8031,8032,8033,8034,8035,8036,8037,8038,8039,8040,8041,8042,8043,8044,8045,8046,8047,8048,8049,8050,8051,8052,8053,8054,8055,8056,8057,8058,8059,8060,8061,8062,8063,8064,8065,8066,8067,8068,8069,8070,8071,8072,8073,8074,8075,8076,8077,8078,8079,8080,8083,8084,8085,8086,8087,8088,8089,8090,8093,8094,8095,8096,8097,8098,8099,8100,8101,8102,8103,8104,8105,8106,8107,8108,8109,8110,8111,8112,8113,8114,8115,8116,8119,8120,8121,8122,8123,8124,8125,8126,8127,8128,8129,8130,8131,8132,8133,8134,8135,8136,8137,8138,8139,8140,8141,8142,8143,8144,8145,8146,8147,8148,8149,8150,8151,8152,8153,8154,8155,8156,8157,8158,8159,8160,8161,8162,8163,8166,8167,8168,8169,8170,8171,8172,8173,8174,8175,8176,8177,8178,8179,8180,8181,8182,8183,8184,8185,8186,8187,8188,8189,8190,8191,8192,8193,8194,8195,8196,8197,8198,8199,8200,8201,8202,8203,8204,8205,8206,8207,8208,8209,8210,8211,8212,8213,8214,8215,8216,8217,8218,8219,8220,8221,8222,8223,8224,8225,8226,8227,8228,8229,8230,8231,8232,8233,8234,8235,8236,8237,8238,8240,8241,8242,8246,8247,8248,8252,8253,8254,8258,8259,8260,8264,8265,8266,8270,8271,8272,8273,8274,8275,8276,8277,8278,8279,8280,8281,8282,8283,8284,8285,8286,8287,8288,8289,8290,8291,8294,8295,8296,8297,8298,8299,8300,8301,8302,8304,8305,8306,8307,8308,8309,8310,8311,8312,8313,8314,8315,8316,8317,8318,8319,8320,8321,8322,8323,8324,8325,8326,8327,8328,8329,8330,8331,8332,8333,8334,8335,8336,8337,8338,8339,8340,8341,8342,8343,8344,
8345,8346,8347,8348,8349,8350,8352,8353,8354,8355,8356,8357,8358,8360,8361,8362,8431,8432,8433,8434,8463,8464,8465,8466,8467,8478,8479,8480,8481,8482,8483,8494,8495,8496,8497,8498,8499,8507,8508,8509,8510,8511,8512,8513,8514,8515,8523,8524,8525,8526,8527,8528,8529,8530,8531,8539,8540,8541,8542,8543,8547,8549,8552,8553,8556,8559,8560,8563,8564,10356,10357,10358,10359,10360,10361,10362,10363,10364,10365,10366,10367,10368,10369,10370,10371,10372,10373,10374,10386,10387,10388,10393,10394,10395,10396,10397,10398,10399,10449,10450,10451,10456,10457,10458,10459,10460,10461,10483,10548,10842,10847,10852
    }
    Weights: *519 {
        a: 0.00240023992955685,0.00430000014603138,0.00350034981966019,0.00120000005699694,0.000200019989279099,0.00980097986757755,0.00499999988824129,0.01970000192523,0.00990098994225264,0.035707138478756,0.0185018517076969,0.0623937658965588,0.033396665006876,0.105110518634319,0.0757924243807793,0.179082110524178,0.13910000026226,0.013798619620502,0.013399999588728,0.0275055021047592,0.0269000008702278,0.0493950620293617,0.048200000077486,0.0841084122657776,0.0820082053542137,0.136999994516373,0.13340000808239,0.226000010967255,0.220100000500679,0.0472999997437,0.0808000043034554,0.133586660027504,0.224577531218529,0.0017001701053232,0.00480048032477498,0.000899909995496273,0.0110988905653358,0.00350035005249083,0.00960096064954996,0.00170000013895333,0.0222022216767073,0.00680136028677225,0.0290029011666775,0.0170999988913536,0.104789525270462,0.00340068014338613,0.0397000014781952,0.0133013306185603,0.0502999983727932,0.0290999989956617,0.0659065991640091,0.00659999996423721,0.0672932714223862,0.0258000008761883,0.0838000029325485,0.0470000021159649,0.0417041704058647,0.0129000004380941,0.10980000346899,0.0503949634730816,0.142028406262398,0.0764000043272972,0.0248000007122755,0.0252025201916695,0.182218223810196,0.00970000028610229,0.0192980710417032,0.0339000001549721,0.0555944368243217,0.0873000025749207,0.139286071062088,0.00959999952465296,0.0192980710417032,0.033500000834465,0.0545000024139881,0.0843999981880188,0.131599992513657,0.00850085075944662,0.0170999988913536,0.029399998486042,0.0468953102827072,0.0710999965667725,0.108689121901989,0.00689999992027879,0.0139013901352882,0.0242999996989965,0.0398000031709671,0.0597000010311604,0.0888999998569489,0.00240000011399388,0.00469999993219972,0.00889822095632553,0.015498448163271,0.0262026209384203,0.0452045202255249,0.000400000018998981,0.000799920002464205,0.00160016003064811,0.0031999999191612,0.00650000013411045,0.0130000002682209,0.00789999961853027,0.00700070010498166,0.0487999990582466,0.0830999985337257,0.13629999756813,0.227800011634827,
0.0131986793130636,0.0136986300349236,0.0263999961316586,0.02730000205338,0.0160016007721424,0.0139013901352882,0.100089997053146,0.0858914107084274,0.143514364957809,0.236076399683952,0.288500010967255,0.223422348499298,0.121500000357628,0.0781000033020973,0.0348000042140484,0.0204979497939348,0.260600000619888,0.183699995279312,0.206399992108345,0.403200000524521,0.463299989700317,0.348899990320206,0.164700001478195,0.108710870146751,0.0527999997138977,0.0400959886610508,0.430843085050583,0.40464049577713,0.339600026607513,0.470752894878387,0.442299991846085,0.31470000743866,0.184518456459045,0.134086593985558,0.0837000012397766,0.0749074891209602,0.456645667552948,0.442955672740936,0.403840392827988,0.44200000166893,0.377400010824203,0.323167681694031,0.225322529673576,0.175200000405312,0.125200003385544,0.104189582169056,0.47350001335144,0.480800032615662,0.467946827411652,0.413058698177338,0.0705070570111275,0.062993697822094,0.0500949919223785,0.0372037179768085,0.366763323545456,0.0221999995410442,0.0318000018596649,0.041700005531311,0.0393960624933243,0.0296000000089407,0.011001099832356,0.00550054991617799,0.00270054000429809,0.00970000121742487,0.0124000003561378,0.0203000027686357,0.0268973093479872,0.0223999992012978,0.00740000000223517,0.00340000004507601,0.00170016998890787,0.00490000005811453,0.00620000017806888,0.0101010100916028,0.0134013397619128,0.0115000000223517,0.00360036012716591,0.0459000021219254,0.0630936920642853,0.0871087089180946,0.120312035083771,0.1317999958992,0.103510357439518,0.072500005364418,0.0460953935980797,0.0194980520755053,0.0107010696083307,0.0157999992370605,0.0253025311976671,0.0337000004947186,0.0337999984622002,0.0220999997109175,0.0142985703423619,0.00709929037839174,0.00350000010803342,0.120212018489838,0.170682936906815,0.306500017642975,0.389499992132187,0.472547292709351,0.0124000012874603,0.00310030998662114,0.0015999999595806,0.0595999993383884,0.00620000017806888,0.243848770856857,0.159215912222862,0.367863208055496,0.362472504377365,0.360763907432556,0.0741000026464462,
0.00500000035390258,0.00250000017695129,0.162299990653992,0.232600003480911,0.308830857276917,0.273800015449524,0.0207000020891428,0.0412958711385727,0.0744074434041977,0.195099994540215,0.103310324251652,0.132200002670288,0.352999985218048,0.368699997663498,0.369100004434586,0.397839784622192,0.425842583179474,0.401159882545471,0.384400010108948,0.351700007915497,0.332100033760071,0.307400017976761,0.253174692392349,0.188718885183334,0.114722937345505,0.000499950023368001,0.000999900046736002,0.0239000003784895,0.00159984000492841,0.0450954921543598,0.109010890126228,0.159284085035324,0.197339460253716,0.238400012254715,0.140500009059906,0.249500006437302,0.256974309682846,0.303269684314728,0.200620055198669,0.178999990224838,0.197919800877571,0.270027011632919,0.113288670778275,0.296299993991852,0.351335138082504,0.371162921190262,0.16159999370575,0.318300008773804,0.228577151894569,0.448399990797043,0.455745577812195,0.455700010061264,0.454954504966736,0.0794999971985817,0.0401000007987022,0.108589150011539,0.0550054982304573,0.129712969064713,0.0664000064134598,0.135199993848801,0.0687137469649315,0.144800007343292,0.110511057078838,0.0705000013113022,0.099990002810955,0.138799995183945,0.179000005125999,0.219099998474121,0.274399995803833,0.121412143111229,0.00989999994635582,0.00490048993378878,0.170782938599586,0.234623461961746,0.301269859075546,0.366600006818771,0.407599985599518,0.364936500787735,0.383561611175537,0.386261343955994,0.168783128261566,0.0147000001743436,0.00730073032900691,0.179117918014526,0.236699998378754,0.293770641088486,0.379999995231628,0.446499973535538,0.360799998044968,0.369563043117523,0.346734702587128,0.300999999046326,0.175500005483627,0.100100003182888,0.00410041026771069,0.00250025023706257,0.00100000004749745,0.273999989032745,0.147900000214577,0.094700001180172,0.00229977001436055,0.00110011000651866,0.186981290578842,0.134886503219604,0.0750000029802322,0.0940999984741211,0.0218000002205372,0.000499999965541065,0.123400002717972,0.0233999993652105,0.0019000000320375,0.0118000004440546,
0.00479952013120055,0.000499950023368001,0.0059000002220273,0.00240000034682453,0.000200020003831014,0.386600017547607,0.317799985408783,0.298599988222122,0.252700001001358,0.314999997615814,0.300599992275238,0.2483000010252,0.129399999976158,0.260326027870178,0.204099997878075,0.186418637633324,0.0401000007987022,0.0176035221666098,0.000600000028498471,0.251000016927719,0.269600003957748,0.165283486247063,0.0414000004529953,0.224399998784065,0.188899993896484,0.146099999547005,0.0108989104628563,0.21647834777832,0.144199997186661,0.0639936029911041,0.0116999996826053,0.115711562335491,0.113600000739098,0.0214000009000301,0.0447999984025955,0.00670000026002526,0.129112914204597,0.0834999978542328,0.0434000007808208,0.00820000097155571,0.0883088335394859,0.0898000001907349,0.0109999999403954,0.043699998408556,0.0260973889380693,0.0784000009298325,0.0511999987065792,0.022299999371171,0.00410000002011657,0.060093991458416,0.063000001013279,0.00580000039190054,0.0324999988079071,0.0177999995648861,0.00699929986149073,0.0263000000268221,0.0186000000685453,0.0110000008717179,0.0020000000949949,0.029100002720952,0.0303000006824732,0.00290029007010162,0.0158984120935202,0.00879999995231628,0.00719999987632036,0.0273000001907349,0.013399999588728,0.0295000001788139,0.147499993443489,0.0217000003904104,0.0974097400903702,0.0247000027447939,0.217600002884865,0.206879317760468,0.143900007009506,0.0434999987483025,0.0288971103727818,0.0296970326453447,0.0301969796419144,0.0422957688570023,0.0484048388898373,0.046000000089407,0.0249000024050474,0.005899409763515,0.0180981904268265,0.139313936233521,0.114399999380112,0.0761076137423515,0.0366000011563301,0.156384363770485,0.000899909937288612,0.000699930009432137,0.000500000023748726,0.00120000005699694,0.00109999999403954,0.000600000028498471,0.000300000014249235,0.00960000045597553,0.0117000006139278,0.00920000020414591,0.0061006098985672,0.00300000002607703,0.00650000013411045,0.0183000005781651,0.0225000027567148,0.0199999995529652,0.0140000004321337,0.00810081046074629,0.0106000006198883,
0.0490049012005329,0.0696930289268494,0.059405941516161,0.0412000007927418,0.0229977015405893,0.00260000000707805,0.00510102044790983,0.00980098079890013,0.0274000000208616,0.0585058517754078,0.0742925703525543,0.0590000003576279,0.0397039763629436,0.0204000025987625,0.00270000007003546,0.00540054077282548,0.0103000001981854,0.0307000000029802,0.0661066174507141,0.0811081156134605,0.0525052510201931,0.0318999998271465,0.0136986300349236,0.00259974040091038,0.00700000021606684,0.0131013114005327,0.0342965684831142,0.0169016905128956,0.033100001513958,0.0445000045001507,0.0151000004261732,0.0384038425981998,0.0267973206937313,0.00679931975901127,0.00340034021064639,0.0135013507679105,0.00679931975901127,0.326367378234863,0.202420234680176,0.122000008821487,0.074800007045269,0.0441000014543533,0.0246975310146809,0.0123999994248152,0.407000005245209,0.44154417514801,0.44870001077652,0.450399994850159,0.331699997186661,0.188999995589256,0.102989710867405,0.0449954979121685,0.0407959185540676,0.0337000004947186,0.0236000008881092,0.0118000013753772,0.0838999971747398,0.056994304060936,0.0425000041723251,0.121799997985363,0.123099997639656,0.102989695966244,0.0674067363142967,0.0326000042259693,0.124099999666214,0.111200004816055,0.0306030604988337,0.0234999991953373,0.0122999995946884,0.11259999871254,0.105800002813339,0.0861999988555908,0.0491000041365623,0.0243999995291233,0.108989097177982,0.063900001347065,0.000600000028498471,0.000200020003831014,0.000300000043353066,0.000699930009432137
    }
    Transform: *16 {
        a: -0.123373719334279,-0.99196749922193,-0.027920301987042,0,0.992355646027652,-0.123409809667645,-0.000433905912925563,0,-0.00301521838998339,-0.027760406427305,0.999610006806728,0,-143.172744832652,15.6358909641465,-2.8187465670338,1
    }
    TransformLink: *16 {
        a: -0.123373739421368,0.992355763912201,-0.00301521876826882,0,-0.991967380692227,-0.123409802494671,-0.0277604032298401,0,-0.0279203050840802,-0.000433906111948186,0.999610125984453,0,-2.23216390609741,144.006698608398,2.8200089931488,1
    }
}
```

Fine, so I know where my skin weights are located. This deformer is linked with a model belonging to my skeleton, like the below one:

```
Model: 43880864, "Model::clavicle_r", "LimbNode" {
    Version: 232
    Properties70:  {
        P: "RotationActive", "bool", "", "",1
        P: "InheritType", "enum", "", "",1
        P: "ScalingMax", "Vector3D", "Vector", "",0,0,0
        P: "DefaultAttributeIndex", "int", "Integer", "",0
        P: "Lcl Translation", "Lcl Translation", "", "A",-2.5624293094302,24.4011353780869,1.75273844028327
        P: "Lcl Rotation", "Lcl Rotation", "", "A+",-1.59647649138759,0.126098006759319,97.8618363489333
        P: "MHName", "KString", "", "U", "clavicle_r"
    }
    Culling: "CullingOff"
}
```

This model seems related to a PoseNode element:

```
    PoseNode:  {
        Node: 43880864
        Matrix: *16 {
            a: -0.123373724520206,-0.991967499256134,-0.0279203020036221,-0,0.992355644702911,-0.123409815132618,-0.000433906068792567,-0,-0.00301521853543818,-0.0277604050934315,0.999610006809235,0,-143.172744750977,15.6358909606934,-2.81874656677246,1
        }
    }
```

Also there are several animation data linked to the above model, which are composed by an AnimationCurveNode, like this one...:

```
AnimationCurveNode: 41325152, "AnimCurveNode::R", "" {
    Properties70:  {
        P: "d|X", "Number", "", "A",0
        P: "d|Y", "Number", "", "A",0
        P: "d|Z", "Number", "", "A",0
    }
}
```

...And 3 AnimationCurve linked to the AnimationCurveNode, like the below example:

```
AnimationCurve: 43322352, "AnimCurve::", "" {
    Default: 6.83911848068237
    KeyVer: 4009
    KeyTime: *30 {
        a: 0,1539538600,3079077200,4618615800,6158154400,7697693000,9237231600,10776770200,12316308800,13855847400,15395386000,16934924600,18474463200,20014001800,21553540400,23093079000,24632617600,26172156200,27711694800,29251233400,30790772000,32330310600,33869849200,35409387800,36948926400,38488465000,40028003600,41567542200,43107080800,44646619400
    }
    KeyValueFloat: *30 {
        a: 6.839118,4.812448,2.579699,2.663273,2.931432,0.4413721,-2.407341,-2.829627,-2.010718,-0.2999563,0.4959856,0.8600912,2.385289,7.922067,12.00326,14.10983,16.25888,17.10504,13.76837,11.45222,7.290313,4.249648,3.026491,4.031856,4.573201,5.226569,5.798617,6.815637,7.556128,6.839089
    }
    ;KeyAttrFlags: Cubic|TangeantAuto|GenericTimeIndependent
    KeyAttrFlags: *1 {
        a: 8456
    }
    ;KeyAttrDataFloat: RightAuto:0, NextLeftAuto:0
    KeyAttrDataFloat: *4 {
        a: 0,0,218434821,0
    }
    KeyAttrRefCount: *1 {
        a: 30
    }
}
```

As I said, I'm comfortable with several concepts in 3d animated models, so the weights and KeyTime/KeyData structures are pretty clear for me.

But I just cannot understand which data I should use to build my skeleton, as all the following ones may potentially do the job (or even perhaps none of them?):

- Should I use the Transform matrix from the deformer?, or
- Should I use the TransformLink instead?, or
- Should I use the Lcl Translation/Lcl Rotation available in the model?, or
- Should I use the matrix available in the pose node?, or
- Should I use a mix of all these values?

And what are the difference e.g between Transform and TransformLink matrices?

In the same way, the available data for the animation let me also puzzled, as there is a float value which should be applied with the time... but to what? And what this value means, as it's obviously not a percentage (i.e between 0 and 1)?

If someone may explain me a little more in details what these values are meaning, and how I may use them, I would be greatfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a month of search and headache, I finally managed to understand how all these data were working together.

The **"Lcl Translation"** and **"Lcl Rotation"** contained in the **Model** structure represent a **bone** in the **skeleton**, once combined into a matrix. The models hierarchy is the skeleton itself.

The **TransformLink** matrix contained in the **Deformer** structure is the matrix to combine with the bone matrix, to transform each vertex to their final location. Note that **this matrix should be inverted** before be used.

Finally the **AnimationCurve** structures linked with a parent **AnimationCurveNode** contain the new values to apply to each bone matrix they are linked with. They contain the 3 x, y and z values which represent a new local translation or rotation over the time, where "AnimCurveNode::T" represents a translation while "AnimCurveNode::R" represents a rotation.

I couldn't find any usage for the **Transform** matrix contained in the **Deformer** structure, as well as for the **PoseNode** hierarchy.

If you're interested by the final result, my FBX reader project is available here: https://github.com/Jeanmilost/Demos/tree/master/Visual%20Studio/OpenGL/FBX